# Node Js Firestore accessing a database value with a space

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

new to node Js expecting this to be very easy!

in node JS with Firestore i want to access  "display name": James, "Age": 22

Age has no space so i can just put

```
const newValue = doc.data();
             const age = newValue.Age;
```

but display name contains a space 
how to you type this?

```
 const displayName = newValue.displayName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `[]` notation to get at the property.

So:

```
const displayName = newValue["display name"];
```